# Change style of a Button when its Disabled ( IsEnabled=False )

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a UWP Question. How can I change style of a Button when it’s Disabled (IsEnabled=False)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you do it.

```
<StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Click Me" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,
                ElementName=button, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>

            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, 
                ElementName=button, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>

        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>

    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" IsChecked="True" />

</StackPanel>
```

Don't forget you need to reference the Behaviors SDK.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 14):

Microsoft added the [VisualStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) (known from Silverlight) to the Windows Universal Plattform. Its purpose is to handle the appearance of a control for different states. The "Disabled" state of a button is a good example. The visual states of a control are defined in its ControlTemplate. To customize these States the easiest way is to right click on your button in the designer and choose "Edit Template" then "Edit a Copy...". 
[image]

What this does is it copies the default template of that control to the selected location.
If the control is a Button, you will have a style resource like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now you can see the visual states of the Button and the setters/animations which are associated with them. You can modify them by hand or you can open Microsoft Blend 2015. It has great capabilities for designing visual states. Right-click on your button and click "Edit Template"->"Edit Current" in Blend and you can see all the states your control has on the states tab (left side).

[image]

When you select the "Disabled" state, you will see a red border arround the designer window. The text in the top left corner tells you that "Disabled state recording is on...". This means every change to an object in your control tree is made to the "Disabled" state of the control. For example you can change the Foreground color of the Contentpresenter for the Disabled state. The following animation will be added to your XAML:

```
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF225EFF"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

For some more information about VisualSateManager and where to start take a look at the [New XAML Tools in Visual Studio 2015 and Blend Video on Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/New-XAML-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2015-and-Blend).

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Tnx... it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found the answer on how to do this!
To do this in **XAML** you put this little pyramid.

```
 <Button.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="SteelBlue"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Button.Resources>
```

And for some content here is what it looks like inside of a button.

```
<Button x:Name="AddBtn" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="36"
                    Width="340" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="80" Background="{ThemeResource SlykBrush2}"
                    Click="AddBtn_Click" IsEnabled="False">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="SteelBlue"/>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </Button.Resources>
                <Button.Content>ADD</Button.Content>
            </Button>
```

It is important that the X:keys are exactly these for it to work. Visual Studio will not autofill these either (sadly)

So ResourceDictionary  x:Key="Default" & SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled"

I will place an image here of brush X:keys for some other changes.

[image]