# UWP Commandbar AppButton Foreground when disabled (IsEnabled="False")

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I have a UWP App with a CommandBar. The CommandBar is intended here mainly as a status display and therefore will not contain any clickable buttons. However, to not limit my design posibilities to the Content part of the bar, I want to use disabled AppBarButtons on the right. As there is no need to distinguish them from active buttons, I would like them to have the default foreground instead of the Light Gray which is applied to disabled ones.

From what I have read, this is not directly possible in XAML, so one would need to define a new template or a new button class. I have not found any resource which helps me in that direction.

I would also be happy with a solution which allows me to display right aligned content in the Content part of the bar, and does not require a button at all.

Related: [Change style of a Button when its Disabled ( IsEnabled=False )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437115/change-style-of-a-button-when-its-disabled-isenabled-false)
It is not the same as the XAML code is for a StackPanel and the answer referring to the designer also does not apply since the CommandBar is not visible in the designer.

EDIT: XAML Code (Of course my question refers to ProfileButton)

```
<Page
    x:Class="Device_Reader.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Device_Reader"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="700" Width="959">
    <Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled" Color="Black"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" DefaultLabelPosition="Right"  IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Grid Margin="5,10,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Name="RedFlag" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Source="Assets/flag.svg"/>
                    <Image Name="YellowFlag" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Source="Assets/flag.svg"/>
                    <Image Name="GreenFlag" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Source="Assets/flag.svg"/>
                    <Image Name="BlueFlag" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Source="Assets/flag.svg"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="ConnectionStatusText" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Text="   Off"/>

                </Grid>
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarButton Name="ProfileButton" Label="Profile" IsEnabled="False">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE771;"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a style copy of an `AppBarButton` makes you feel in trouble, then there is a simpler way to achieve your purpose.

The thing we have to do is very simple, change the background color and foreground color of the `AppBarButton` in the **Disabled** state.

Add this code to your Page:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled" Color="White"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now run the application, if you don't apply any other special styles to the `AppBarButton`, then its background color and foreground color will change in the **Disabled** state.

>> *Now explain the reason.*

We created these two color resources to override the default color resources. In the default style of `AppBarButton`, these two system color resources are referenced in the Disabled state. If we rewrite in Page, the color resource in Page has higher priority, and the color will be changed when the `AppBarButton` under the Page is disabled.

---

But your situation is to display the text in the `CommandBar`. If you don't need a button, you might try to use a `StackPanel` instead of a `CommandBar` and then write a `TextBlock` in it.

---

**Update**

`Page.BottomAppBar` seems to reference different color resources, you can consider putting `CommandBar` in `Page.Content` like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Your Main Content-->

    <CommandBar Grid.Row="1">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <!--Other Content-->
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <AppBarButton Name="ProfileButton" Label="Profile" IsEnabled="False">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE771;"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Grid>
```

This will override the resource

Best regards.

Comment: This does not work. I copied your code inmediatly after the <Page> opening tag, and there is no other style being applied to the AppBarButton

Comment: Well, it does indeed reference different ressources, but I can override those within the Commandbar with `<Commandbar.Ressources>`, so I did not need your suggestion (which does work but of course changes the layout of the bar within the window.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, it also provided me with new ideas.