# AppBarButton background Wont be changed when it is Disabled in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
AppBarButton AppBarButton = new AppBarButton();
AppBarButton.Label = "Pictures";
AppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;
AppBarButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
```

When AppBarButton IsEnabled=false. I cant set Background for Appbarbutton and it look like transparent....How to set LightGray color when IsEnabled=false in uwp?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437115/change-style-of-a-button-when-its-disabled-isenabled-false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change style of a Button when its Disabled ( IsEnabled=False )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437115/change-style-of-a-button-when-its-disabled-isenabled-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default style of AppBarButton, there is a "**Disabled**" state. When you disable the AppBarButton, the "Disabled" state will take effect. It set the Background of Root as `{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}`, this is why you didn't set the Background successfully. So you can remove this line and apply new style for AppBarButton, the Background will change.

.xaml:

The line below that is commented causes the transparent background, you can comment or remove it.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <!--<Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>-->
        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
        <Setter Target="AppBarButtonInnerBorder.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundDisabled}"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

.cs:

```
AppBarButton AppBarButton = new AppBarButton();
AppBarButton.Label = "Pictures";
AppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;
AppBarButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
AppBarButton.Style = (Style)this.Resources["AppBarButtonStyle1"];
```

For the complete changed style, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/wcj233/AppBarButton_App/blob/master/AppBarButtonApp/MainPage.xaml).

Comment: which part of code i want to use as style...??Whole Code or Some Part only.....For single property change ,is this need to place whole code??

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/wcj233/AppBarButton_App/blob/master/AppBarButtonApp/MainPage.xaml) is the complete changed style, when I right-click on the AppBarButton from the visual designer, then click on Edit Template -> Edit a copy, it created the default one. I just commented out the line above mentioned. Since setting the Background of AppBarButton as AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled when the button is disabled, you need to change the setting in the style and then apply the new one.